# "Double" composition with CompletableFuture

Tags: java, haskell, java-8, completable-future

I'm trying to avoid nesting `CompletableFuture` when combining 2 independent ones with a `BiFunction` that returns a third one.
Currently, using `thenCombine()` does not cut it:

```
// What I have
public CompletableFuture<CompletableFuture<C>> doStuff() {
    CompletableFuture<A> aFuture = makeSomeA();
    CompletableFuture<B> bFuture = makeSomeB();
    CompletableFuture<CompletableFuture<C>> cFuture = aFuture.thenCombine(bFuture, this::makeSomeC);
    return cFuture;
}

// What I want
public CompletableFuture<C> doStuff() {
    CompletableFuture<A> aFuture = makeSomeA();
    CompletableFuture<B> bFuture = makeSomeB();
    // obv this method does not exist
    CompletableFuture<C> c = aFuture.thenBicompose(bFuture, this::makeSomeC);
} 

private CompletableFuture<A> makeSomeA() {...}
private CompletableFuture<B> makeSomeB() {...}
private CompletableFuture<C> makeSomeC(A a, B b) {...}
```

I'm basically trying to find a way that looks like haskell if there was a `CompletableFuture` monad:

```
doStuff :: CompletableFuture C
doStuff = do
    a <- makeSomeA
    b <- makeSomeB
    makeSomeC a b

makeSomeA :: CompletableFuture A
makeSomeB :: CompletableFuture B
makeSomeC :: A -> B -> CompletableFuture C
```

I read somewhere that `join()` is the `flatMap` of Completable future, so I think I could use this method to do something like `aFuture.thenCombine(bFuture, ((Function<CompletableFuture<C>,C>) CompletableFuture::join).compose(this::makeSomeC)` but I'm not sure this is the proper/advised way to go. And I cannot say that this help readability in any way...

Comment: You're saying that using Java to write Haskell doesn't end up being readable? ;)

Comment: Are you sure that the Haskell code and the Java code are equivalent? To me it look like that in the Haskell code makeSomeA will finish evaluating before makeSomeB can start evaluating. (But I'm not an expert in Haskell concurrency.)

Comment: Lii, that's the beauty of haskell: what looks like imperative code is not. I cannot explain this simply as I don't fully grasp it myself, but I encourage you to read some resource about haskell that will help you get this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To me it looks like `thenCompose` is the direct equivalent of the Haskell `Monad.bind`.

`thenCompose` can be nested in the same way as Haskell monad bind, which is also the result of a do-expression in Haskell. Using that your problem can be solved like this:

```
public CompletableFuture<C> doStuff() {
    CompletableFuture<A> aFuture = makeSomeA();
    CompletableFuture<B> bFuture = makeSomeB();
    return aFuture.thenCompose(a -> bFuture.thenCompose(b -> makeSomeC(a, b)));
}
```

---

#### Explanation of the types

This can be seen by inspecting the types of the functions.

Monad bind -- which is written `>>=` in Haskell -- has the following type:

```
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

`thenCompose` in Java has the following signature:

```
public <U> CompletionStage<U> thenCompose(Function<? super T, ? extends CompletionStage<U>> fn)
```

The above converted to Haskell syntax, with an extra parameter as an explicit `this`, looks like this:

```
thenCompose :: CompletionStage T -> (T -> CompletionStage U) -> CompletionStage U
```

We can see that this has the same structure as the Haskell type. The difference is the names, and the fact Haskell's support for higher-kinded types is not exactly expressed by Java interfaces.

---

#### Note on the Haskell code in the question

But I am a bit puzzled by your Haskell code. To me it looks like your Haskell code is doing the following:

```
public CompletableFuture<C> doStuff() {
    return makeSomeA().thenCompose(a -> makeSomeB().thenCompose(b -> makeSomeC(a, b)));
}
```

That is, waiting until the `makeSomeA` operation has completed before starting on `makeSomeB`. The Java code on the other hand starts the two operations in parallel, then waits for the result before starting on C. But maybe it is a laziness thing.

Comment: That's it, that's the bind equivalent I'm looking for. Too bad there's no do-notation in Java and things are less readable than in haskell. Hard to hit a nail with a screwdriver I guess :) My haskell code actually does nothing, but depending on how the Monad instance would be implemented for CompletableFuture, it could act either sync or async.

Comment: Now I regret I didn't think about this solution first :-) In fact, the answer was in the question title!

Comment: @DidierL: Yeah, there is only a small step from your solution to mine... At first I though about making a comment your solution instead of posting my own. But I also wanted to add more details and discussion so I made a separate answer instead.

Answer (score 6):

I guess the simplest solution is just to apply a `thenCompose(identity())` afterwards:

```
public CompletableFuture<C> doStuff() {
    CompletableFuture<A> aFuture = makeSomeA();
    CompletableFuture<B> bFuture = makeSomeB();
    CompletableFuture<CompletableFuture<C>> cFuture = aFuture.thenCombine(bFuture, this::makeSomeC);
    return cFuture.thenCompose(Function.identity());
}
```

Alternatively, introduce a simple `Pair` class to combine the results of A and B and use `thenCompose()`:

```
public CompletableFuture<C> doStuff() {
    CompletableFuture<A> aFuture = makeSomeA();
    CompletableFuture<B> bFuture = makeSomeB();
    CompletableFuture<Pair<A, B>> cFuture = aFuture.thenCombine(bFuture, Pair::new);
    return cFuture.thenCompose(p -> makeSomeC(p.a, p.b));
}

private static class Pair<A, B> {
    A a;
    B b;

    public Pair(A a, B b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

And a third alternative without `Pair`:

```
public CompletableFuture<C> doStuff() {
    CompletableFuture<A> aFuture = makeSomeA();
    CompletableFuture<B> bFuture = makeSomeB();
    CompletableFuture<Void> cFuture = CompletableFuture.allOf(aFuture, bFuture);
    return cFuture.thenCompose(__ -> makeSomeC(aFuture.join(), bFuture.join()));
}
```

Comment: I like the Function.identity() approach as it is going to work whatever the signature of `makeSomeC` is. What do you think of `return cFuture.join()` ?

Comment: `cFuture.join()` will wait for the result of `makeSomeC()` (i.e. the combination itself), and thus as well for the results of both A and B futures. However you might consider passing the futures as arguments to `makeSomeC()` so that you can call it directly instead.

Comment: That's precisely what I want to avoid. `makeSomeC` could be called from outside of doStuff, and I don't want to force the callers to pass something else than the actual object. Haskell does that perfectly, and that's what I'm trying to replicate. CompletableFuture being a monad and all...

Comment: about `cFuture.join()`: when `cFuture` is a `CompletableFuture<CompletableFuture<C>>` the `join` call is going to return almost immediately. In term of functionnality, it's going to be equivalent to the identity composition (I think). I'd say the identity approach is more function oriented, and the join approach just barely more readable. Thanks for your input !

Comment: These approaches are not equivalent. `join()` will return _almost immediately_ if that future completes _almost immediately_… which is the case only if the 2 combined futures complete _almost immediately_, and the combiner returns _almost immediately_ as well. Calling `join()` is more equivalent to calling `makeSomeC()` directly while joining on the 2 first completable futures.

Comment: maybe nitpicking here. in my java code makeSomeC uses a A and a B, not CompletableFutures. It does however return a CompletableFuture. That's why makeSomeC(a,b).join() (which returns a C) will take time. Howvere in first method doStuff, cFuture is a CompletableFuture<CompletableFuture<C>>. calling join on this is just going to execute the task submission (quick) and should return almost immediately